# How to mock a protected field?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, bdd, xunit.net

I am attempting to mock a protected field in the class `NodeIdGenerator`. I want to set the value of the field in a constructor an then call the `GetNext()` method which belongs to `NodeIdGenerator`.

Im pretty sure my test is OK:

```
public class NodeIdGeneratorTests
{

    [Fact(DisplayName = "Throws OverflowException when Int32.MaxValue " +
        "IDs is exceeded")]
    public void ThrowsOverflowExceptionWhenInt32MaxValueIdsIsExceeded()
    {
        var idGenerator = new NodeIdGeneratorMock(Int32.MaxValue);
        Assert.Throws(typeof(OverflowException), 
            () => { idGenerator.GetNext(); });
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Mocks NodeIdGenerator to allow different starting values of 
    /// PreviousId.
    /// </summary>
    private class NodeIdGeneratorMock : NodeIdGenerator
    {
        private new int? _previousId;

        public NodeIdGeneratorMock(int previousIds)
        {
            _previousId = previousIds;
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is in the mock class. When I call `GetNext()` in my test, it uses the `_previousId` object belonging to the superclass, not the one which I want it to use (in the mock class.)

**So, how do I mock the protected field?**

PS: I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584769/how-do-i-mock-a-private-field) but I can't seem to make head nor tail of it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you've posted declares `_previousId` as `new`, so it hides the base class' field - it doesn't override it. The base class won't use that value when you call `GetNext`, it will use its own field.

Try removing your declaration and just access the base class' protected field.

Comment: Haha, so easy. Thanks. I just removed the line `private new int? _previousId;` and hey presto!

Answer (score 1):

If possible it would be better to make `previousId` a virtual property and override the getter in the mock:

```
public class NodeIdGenerator
{
    protected virtual int? PreviousId { ... }
}

private class NodeIdGeneratorMock : NodeIdGenerator
{
    protected override int? PreviousId
    {
        get { return _previousId; }
    }
}
```