# Mocking a Private Object

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I'm working on tests in C#. I'm trying to mock a function from a reference (using Moq). Below is a simplified version of the code presented.

B.cs:

```
public class DeviceB:
    public DeviceB():
        // do some stuff
        return something;
```

A.cs:

```
using B;
public class DeviceA:
    private static DeviceB deviceB;

    public DeviceA():
        deviceB = DeviceB();
```

To test class `DeviceA` would I like to mock `DeviceB()` to change the behavior of `deviceB`.

I believe this should be possible but I can't figure out how. If you have any ideas or suggestions please let me know. (I'm preferably using the Moq vscode nuget but I'm open for alternatives.)

Comment: It just looks to me like you need to learn Moq.  Don't they provide some examples with their library?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes they provide a lot of examples (https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) but I can't find something relating to my problem, also because `deviceB` is private.

Comment: your question could be answered more easily if you´d provided some actual code, not just a bunch of pseudo-code. In particular how you inject the instance of `DeviceB` is important here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584769

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 choice

Declare `virtual` methods of `DeviceB` class and pass it to deviceA.

```
class DeviceB
{
    public virtual void method1()
    {
        // Code [..]
    }
}

class DeviceA
{
    private DeviceB _deviceb;

    public DeviceA(DeviceB deviceb)
    {
       _deviceb = deviceb;
    }

    // More code [..]
}

class UnitTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mock = new Mock<DeviceB>();
        mock.Setup(..);

        // Act
        var devA = new DeviceA(mock.Object);
        var result = devA.mymethod();

        // Assert
        Assert.....
    }
}
```

Declare interface (better) for DeviceB methods and use it on DeviceA instead of DeviceB; inject the concrete DeviceA into DeviceB

```
interface IDeviceB
{
    void Method1();
    int AnotherMethod(int parm1);
}

class DeviceB : IDeviceB 
{
    // [..] Implementations
}


class DeviceA
{
    private IDeviceB _deviceB;

    public DeviceA(IDeviceB C)
    {
        _deviceB = deviceB;
    }
}

class UnitTest
{
     [Fact]
     public void TestMethod1()
     {
          // Arrange
          var mockedDeviceB = new Mock<IDeviceB>();
          mockedDeviceB.Setup(..);

          // Act
          var devA = new DeviceA(mockedDeviceB.Object);
          var result = devA.anotherMethod(1);

          // Assert
          Assert.....
     }
}
```